# Open a specific member revision via link

Tags: mks-integrity

I can create and send an `integrity://ims-xxxx:1111/si/` link of a file to a colleague which will be open in their MKS client, showing a specific file(member) in its related folder(subproject).

How can I send a link to a specific member revision (one bubble of a tree) so that it still opens in a client and not in a web browser?

Meaning: same functionality as before, but the member history opens automatically and highlights a specific member revision(version).

`integrity://ims-xxxx:1111/si/viewrevision` doesn't work as `integrity` link and even as a `si` command tries to display the content instead of the history tree.

in `integrity://ims-xxxx:1111/si/viewproject=xxxx` i can't specify a member revision

Any ideas? Thanks!